# When are the eigenstates of two operators the same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator, observables

Suppose $\{\left|{u_{n}}\right>\}$ is the set of energy (Hamiltonian) eigenstats. Are they also eigenfunctions of any physically observable operator $\hat{A}$?

Can we use the following eigenvalue equation?

$\hat{A}\left|{u_{n}}\right>=a_{n}\left|{u_{n}}\right>$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this operator $\hat A$ commutes with the Hamiltonian, i.e. $[\hat H, \hat A] = 0$, then both operators share a common set of eigenfunctions.

Here is a general proof:

Suppose $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ share a common set of complete orthonormal eigenfunctions (have the same basis) $\{ | n \rangle \}$, with $\hat A | n \rangle = a_n | n \rangle $ and $\hat B | n \rangle = b_n | n \rangle $, then for all $|\psi \rangle \in \mathcal{H}$

$$
\hat A \hat B |\psi\rangle = \hat A \hat B \sum_n c_n |n\rangle = \hat A \sum_nc_n b_n |n\rangle = \sum_n c_nb_n a_n |n\rangle,
$$

and likewise $\hat B \hat A |\psi\rangle = \sum_n c_n a_n b_n |n \rangle$, and therefore

$$
\hat A \hat B |\psi\rangle - \hat B \hat A | \psi \rangle = 0,
$$

for arbitrary $|\psi\rangle$.

Now we have to proof the other way: suppose $[\hat A, \hat B] = 0$. We want to show that if $|n\rangle$ is a solution of the eigenvalue problem $\hat A |n\rangle = a_n |n \rangle$, then also $\hat B |n\rangle$ is a solution of the same eigenvalue problem. Thus

$$
\hat A (\hat B |n\rangle) = \hat B \hat A |n\rangle = \hat B a_n |n\rangle  = a_n (\hat B |n \rangle),
$$

and if $a_n$ is not degenerate (you can extend the proof for degenerate eigenvalues), we have $\hat B |n\rangle = const. |n\rangle =:b_n |n\rangle $, and $| n \rangle $ is eigenfunction of $\hat B$ (with eigenvalue $b_n$).